# Perl Regex, picking inverse to match

Tags: regex, perl

My input to regex:

`ath_rxbuf_alloc: nbf->data=83eac058 (nbf->head=83eac038) is not aligned to 32 bytes (len=3900)`

On the above input, I need to remove address and numbers and would need a output like,

`ath_rxbuf_alloc: nbf->data (nbf->head) is not aligned to bytes (len)`

Expression I've used: `/\=\w+\d|\d+/ig`

As we know, my expression picks words and digits from `=` character; now I just need to inverse pick the whole and need to combine the whole as single element.

Will really be grateful If someone could help resolve this.

Comment: wouldnt it be simpler to just REMOVE the stuff you did capture? ( `s/..//` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you need to invert anything. Take the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'ath_rxbuf_alloc: nbf->data=83eac058 (nbf->head=83eac038) is not aligned to 32 bytes (len=3900)';
$str =~ s/=[[:xdigit:]]+|\d+//g;

print "Result: $str\n";
```

#### output

```
Result: ath_rxbuf_alloc: nbf->data (nbf->head) is not aligned to  bytes (len)
```

You can simply replace all matches by nothing.

Comment: Thats awesome, am also trying the same instead of picking inverse.

Thank You :)

Comment: `[[:xdigit:]]` is better written as `\p{hex}` in modern versions of Perl.

Comment: @Borodin Why is `\p{hex}` better?

Comment: @melpomene: Because it's more modern, concise, flexible, and expressive. POSIX doesn't take any account of Unicode, and that is a big shortcoming for the modern world where software has to work well in multiple different languages. ASCII is based on English, and Britain and North America have historically been slow to concede that encodings for all languages should be the norm.  Oh, and people *still* often don't understand that POSIX `[:category:]` can share a character class with other characters and POSIX categories.

Comment: @Borodin Modern doesn't mean better, and I don't see how it's more flexible or expressive. That leaves concise, which basically means it's shorter. I'm unconvinced. (Multiple language support doesn't really matter for a category like "hex digit".)

Comment: @melpomene: I suspect that you were never going to be convinced in the first place. Did you not read my comment after the first sentence? You don't see how it's more expressive? Take a look at [perluniprops](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) to see how much more you can do with Unicode properties than POSIX categories, and if you weren't working with English data then you may well need several of those properties. Do you really want to mix two standards in your code? *"Modern doesn't mean better"* That's fine, just stick to FORTRAN and you'll be happy.

Comment: @Borodin I did, but I didn't understand your last sentence. I wasn't talking about `\p` vs. `[:` `:]` in general, just `[[:xdigit:]]` vs. `\p{hex}`. And we're not working with English data, we're working with memory addresses in hex format; if anything we want `\p{ahex}`. I'm fine with mixing dozens of standards in my code.